# Deployed to meteor app to Galaxy and mLab - Error No schema found

Tags: meteor, galaxy, mlab

I deployed my meteor app to Galaxy and created my mongodb on mLab. I added the user account required. I did not import my database into mLab.

I am getting the error.  Error: No scheme found in URI

Will meteor recreate the data collections on mLab?

Comment: What does the URI look like? Is the prefix `mongodb://`?